# Ag-grid pivot avoid column aggregation

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an Ag-grid pivot table with row groups and column defs.
Is there a way to hide the "Total" column while still having an expandable pivot column groups and the same aggFunc for the row groups?

Example:
The current state
[image: The current state]

What I want
[image: What I want]

Code:

```
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'country', rowGroup: true, enableRowGroup: true },
    { field: 'athlete', rowGroup: true, enableRowGroup: true },
    { field: 'sport', pivot: true, enablePivot: true },
    { field: 'year', pivot: true, enablePivot: true },
    { field: 'gold', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'silver', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'bronze', aggFunc: 'sum' },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    maxWidth: 140,
    filter: true,
    resizable: true,
  },
  autoGroupColumnDef: {
    minWidth: 180,
  },
  pivotMode: true,
  pivotColumnGroupTotals: 'before',
};
```

Thanks!